# STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error} The initial session process or system process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2, fatal-error, hyper-v, hard-drive

I'm encountering such an error after expanding disk (done by Hyper-V) space on virtual machine.

**STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error}  The initial session process or system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of (0x00000000) (0xc000012d 0x001003f0).**

The virtual server there is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition, which is also Domain Controller, now my whole environment is down :/
I've tried to repair Windows - but there is no restore point, and using command line, I've also tried the sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR /OFFWINDIR, but got error "Windows Resource
Protection could not perform the requested operation"

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but have you found an answer to this? I'm in a similar boat but fortunately don't have the whole domain down. Just a Sharepoint provider.

Comment: No, I had to rebuild the whole domain. There was no time to investigate more, but would be glad to get the answer. Microsoft support team did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

I initially responded to this question to ask if Christof ever found a solution. That's not allowed, so my post was deleted.

I'm back to share that I solved the above problem for myself using a mix-and-match set of backed-up registry files. 
I believe the only reason this worked for me is that there had been ZERO changes to the server between the different times the registry files were backed up. Most of the registry files I used in the recovery were from `c:\windows\system32\config\system\regbak`, but the SOFTWARE file had a timestamps too close to the time of my initial failure, so I used one that I had created in `\windows\tmp` when I initially began this recovery process. I followed a guide which apparently was deleted but you can find references by searching on [site:microsoft.com kb307545](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amicrosoft.com+kb307545), Also make sure you have a backup of the COMPONENTS hive/file.

Comment: Link is now a 404. If you can remember what it was, or what to Google, it would be useful if you posted that here.